# Might additional spacial dimensions provide higher processing efficiency in computing?

Tags: metaphysics, computation

I've been contemplating the possibility of our universe and physics being a big computer simulation. But unlike the writer of [this Oxford paper](http://www.simulation-argument.com/simulation.html), I have in mind the simulation not being later humans or advanced being simulating their own galaxy's history, but rather an entity in an environment not within our universe, simulating our reality and all of its physics, in some environment where computing such a a large simulation might be possible.

So my curiosity is whether additional spacial dimensions might make for better computers.

For a simplified example, our computers in 3D space are more easily capable of simulating 2 dimensions than 3. Perhaps a 4D computer, then, might simulate more easily a 3D space. Or a 5D computer, etc etc assuming that such a universe exists.

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you're suggesting this world is a simulation in 4D? I find that 'the fourth dimension' is often used for just 'something we can't understand' - so please confirm that this is not like that.

Comment: @Keelan we actually do understand the fourth dimension to a pretty interesting extent. It's mysterious, at least to me, because I don't understand the setting or context where a 4D world can / would exist, but I do understand that there is an extra axis onto which space can be observed and filled. That fact alone would seemingly have very interesting and complex effects on computing.

Comment: when you play computer game, like Battlefield or Quake - its already 4D simulation - XYZt. What's you question ?

Comment: @CuriousWebDeveloper well, too bad. Guy called Einstein (and bunch of his friends, like Lorentz) would have disagreed with you, but they died long ago. Anyway, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Mathematics_of_spacetimes

Comment: Regarding 4-dimentional SPACE, well, you need to prove one exists, for starters.

Comment: @c69 not for the purpose of this question I don't.... Wikipedia will talk about it for you though, if you'd like. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space

Comment: I propose to put this question on hold as the philosophical problem here is ill-defined and probably too broad and reopen it when these problems are resolved.

Comment: Actually, your video game is 6-dimensional, X x Y x R x G x B x t.  You imagine Z...  Point being, 'dimension' has at least four or five meanings here, most of them unrelated to a real fourth spatial dimension, which is both silly and not helpful.

Comment: @jobermark 4 dimensional space is something that we may never be able to study directly, but it might just affect us more than we think, whether that effect be meta forces interacting from neighbor universes, or the container in which ours exists. Thought towards scientific theories for creators and outer structures / containers of our universe, while being a long shot, ultimately have a chance of putting us closer to answers about the way and reasons things work in-universe, which is not silly. It's philosophy ;)

Comment: But philosophy is not just speculation ignoring all facts and theories in existence.  A fourth macroscopic spatial dimension would create inverse-cube laws.  Period.  When we find one, we might start caring.

Comment: @jobbermark my point is that we probably won't find one in our universe, but our universe might be affected by outside universes in 4D. Or our universe could be within a 4D container. 4D contemplation shouldn't be ruled out as silly, since 4D physics might affect us metaphysically. My question was simply a theoretical one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough we have an answer: The [Blue Gene/Q has a 5D torus interconnect](https://inspirehep.net/record/1216422/files/Lattice%202012_020.pdf), meaning any software or logic developed for it would STRONGLY resemble the structure you are looking for.  Developers are encouraged to think in terms which leverage this 5D structure.

This is efficient in 3D space because much of the propagation time between nodes is in the computer, not the fiber optic cables.  If the latencies were simply from the fiber optics, it would be more effective to think of it as a 3D network, but the reality of hardware means they found it more optimal to have a 5D interconnect and treat all dimensions the same (even though some dimensions may have longer length fiberoptic cables)

Comment: I just read the entire document. I understood about 15% of it, and now have a higher respect for IBM supercomputer engineers, and those poor software engineers tasked with developing instructions optimized for a 4D torus "processing cycle".

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you mean by power, but by the standards of what computation theory generally considers power, this is a somewhat bizarre question, for how commonly it seems to arise.

In a Turing machine model, all computing is reducible to something 1-dimensional with no loss of generality.  (2 if you are counting time, and reducing the Turing machine to a tiling of something.)  So dimension disappears from consideration.

And relative to "Big O's" it also lacks some sense.  Computer connections are not propagated in any particularly direct spatial manner, two signals can take equally long to reach the same place even if one follows natural space and the other uses a slightly better conduit.  From a direct efficiency point of view, therefore, it is graph-theoretic dimension that matters, and any graph-theoretic dimension can be modeled in 3D space.  Spatial dimensions can decrease the multiplier in a speed calculation, but not the order of growth.

From the points of view where dimensionality does bear on the question, is not really an aspect of computing, but of mechanical engineering as applied to it.

From another direction, 4 spatial dimensions would make for a lovely universe, but it is not ours.  Folks become strongly attached to the notion of 4D space before they realize that basic Newtonian physics indicates we cannot have four macroscopic dimensions.  If we did, we would encounter some basic field effects that decrease as the cube of the distance from their origin.  These should be numerous.  But we never see them.

And we would have to make really serious reasons for why radiant energy itself would not be an inverse-cube field effect.  Energy should not obey an inverse-square law in 4D space.  Given that, if we have any additional dimensions, they are all either microscopic (curved far too tightly to have any use for computer engineering) or temporal.